# jquery .load() is bringing more data than I'm asking for

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a cross site get for a menu listing from d1.test.com to d2.test.com, and it works...but the problem is that it's also pulling back other data outside of the element I want. So for this situation, I'm getting everything in the `<header>` tag, but `$('#mainNav').load('https://d1.test.com header');` (which I've run independently in the console to make sure) is also pulling some other content from d1 that is well outside of the `<header>` tag.

1. Why is that?
2. How do I get only the data between the start and end `<header>` tags like I expect?

ETA:
Here is the html (that was asked for in the comments) on d1 that d2 is pulling over, plus the location of the trasparent.gif which is not within the header tag:

```
 <div class="auxnav">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#skip-to-content">
            <img src="/images/Transparent.gif" alt="Skip to content." width="1" height="1">
        </a>
        <ul id="AuxNavigation" class="CMSListMenuUL">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<header role="heading">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
        menu items here
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Since it shouldn't do that in the first place, there's no way to tell it not to do that.

Comment: Can you show an example of the `d1.test.com` response, and point out which parts of the content are being pulled in?

Comment: @Barmar `S.fn.init [nav#mainNav.CMSListMenuUL]` is the full header and then it's pulling a bunch of things like this: `Transparent.gif:1 GET https://d2.test.com/images/Transparent.gif 404 (Not Found)` - "Transparent.gif" is a relative link on d1...

Comment: Please show the HTML that's being returned.

Comment: We need to see what's nested inside and what isn't.

Comment: jQuery has to parse all the HTML that's returned so it can extract the part it that needs to be inserted into the DOM. That may cause it to try to fetch image sources, even if they're not displayed.

Comment: @Barmar - took me a while to understand what you meant, but I hope this is the html you were asking for.

Comment: Where is `Transparent.gif` being put in the DOM?

Comment: If it's just causing an error in the console, you can ignore that. It's a side effect of parsing all the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar - first, if you can make a coherent Answer out of all of this, I'll mark it correct. Second, I need to learn to read the docs better: https://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments - It says what you said regarding the loading of all the html, then discarding anything it doesn't need, which means I can ignore the console messages like you said. So you helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Last thing: the reason I'm seeing errors is b/c it's not the same origin, so relative links are simply failing as they are given d2 as their absolute url, instead of d1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not actually loading the elements outside `<header>`. It's just parsing the entire returned HTML so that it can then select the nested element that you want. And when there are `<img>` elements in it, this triggers trying to load them, which can cause errors in the console if the images don't exist.

This does cause additional network overhead, so if you can reorganize the server files to split this out into a more specific file, without the surrounding elements, that may be best. But for now you can just ignore the 404 console errors from the images.